# Apex PMD SuppressWarnings breaks Prettier document formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, apex, prettier, pmd

I've recently installed PMD and it's working... however, when I try to suppress a specific warning:

```
@SuppressWarnings('PMD.EmptyStatementBlocks')
if (a == b) {
  // empty statement block
}
```

This works fine... insofar as it suppresses the warning, but it breaks the Prettier plugin document formatting:

```
["ERROR" - 9:59:32 AM] Error formatting document.
Error: Unexpected token '@'.. Syntax(error = UnexpectedToken(loc = (11, 5, 67, 68), token = '@'))
```

What am I doing wrong?